# Mule sftp inbound connector stopped polling files after processing 20K files

Tags: sftp, polling, threadpoolexecutor, mulesoft, inbound

Use case: process large number of files(30K files per day) using SFTP inbound

Issue: After processing 20K files, SFTP inbound connector is not polling files, it remains idle

Current impl: We have used Queued Asynchronous Processing Strategy at flow level. Flow got stopped after processing 20K files.
Even got similar issue when tried with Synchronous processing strategy. Used minThread=8,  threadWaitTimeout=-1

At SFTP connector level we used Thread configuration, like maxTreadsIdle=16,

Mule Runtime: 3.8.3

we have used Queued Asynchronous Processing Strategy at flow level. Flow got stopped after processing 20K files.
Even got similar issue when tried with Synchronous processing strategy. Used minThread=8,  threadWaitTimeout=-1

Below are exceptions we got while trying with different approaches.

Root Exception stack trace:
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: ThreadPoolExecutor did not accept within 30000 MILLISECONDS

Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.service.FailedToQueueEventException: The queue for 'SEDA Stage mypi_gw_formsFlow.stage1' did not accept new event within -1 MILLISECONDS.

Comment: how many cores processors you are using? do you have enough memory ?. I guess 30 sec interval may not be enough for processing big files.

Answer (score 0):

This issue and solutions are explained in this KB article : https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Error-The-queue-for-SEDA-queue-name-did-not-accept-new-event-within-30000-MILLISECONDS

Comment: we are already tried with synchronous processing strategry and faced same issue.